# sort multiple columns of certain range

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort multiple columns of a certain range. My sheet has 4 columns (A,B,C,D) and 80 rows... however, I want to sort by column D. However, I only want to sort in descending order between rows 2-20. Can someone please help me with this code?

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("A2:D20").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D20") _
     , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:D20")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you recorded a macro to see the code Excel uses?

Comment: I can't do that because the range will vary each time.

Comment: This is what I got from recording a macro, by selecting A2:D20 then sorting on column D in descending order: http://pastebin.com/dkaE8HPt . What variation is there to this?

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
Range("A2:D20").Sort key1:=Cells(20, 4), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
```